# Can some amount of gravity be caused by virtual particles?

Tags: gravity, virtual-particles

On the scale of a galaxy, can vacuum-based pairs of virtual particles be noticed gravitationally? Even though they are short-lived, shouldn't their mass and numbers be enough to be measured/felt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as far as anyone can tell, virtual particles in the vacuum should gravitate, and generate a huge spacetime curvature everywhere, which isn't observed. This is the famous [cosmological constant problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#Predictions).